# Mongodb: Updating documents with a slice of the fields value

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to update multiple documents in mongodb which contains some unneeded string. So I need to update documents with a `slice` of part of the string in a field.

I have something like this in my db.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58a04a6c377c443a3af3dbf9"),
    "studentNumber" : "S1859/0113",
    "gender" : "M",
    "studentName" : "Had To change this",
    "points" : "34",
    "division" : "FLD",
    "subjects" : "CIV-D   HIST-F   GEO-F   KISW-F   ENGL-F   BIO-F   B/MATH-F",
    "examType" : "CSEE",
    "examYear" : "2011",
    "schoolNumber" : "S1859",
    "schoolName" : "CHANGED SECONDARY SCHOOL",
    "__v" : 0
```

}

Note the `studentNumber` field has `S1859/0113` and the `schoolNumber` has the `"S1859"`. Now I need to slice the text `S1859` in `studentNumber` field to just remain with `0113`.

I tried

`db.results.find().forEach(function(e) { e.studentNumber = e.studentNumber.split('/').slice(1); e.save() })`

But that gave an error `e.save()` is not a function.

I'm not sure how to do this in:

`db.results.update({studentNumber: {$regex: /[PS]{1}[0-9]{4}\/[0-9]{4}/}}, {condition to use}, false, true)`.

Not sure what condition I should put so to update the field in that same document by slice-ing it.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `forEach`, you can use :

```
db.results.find().forEach(
    function(e) {
        e.studentNumber = e.studentNumber.split('/').slice(1).toString();
        db.results.save(e);
    })
```

Comment: Thank you, It worked! (Tho not as expected) but it updated records and now I have to use something else rather than methods above..